# It's possible to build libstdc++ and statically hard-code it to a given GCC version?

Tags: gcc, libstdc++

My main problem is that I have a system where the official supported GCC version is the 4.6.2/4.6.3 ( it depends if you update or not ) which is pretty old and I also need some new C++11 feature and all the improvement from the newer GCC releases.

I would like to build GCC in a way that:

- the `libstdc++` it's contained in the local GCC installation, something like a "portable" installation I guess.
- GCC doesn't search inside the system for an alternative `libstdc++` and only uses the given and builtin `libstdc++` release
- even if I speficy, with `-I` `-L` `-B`, an alternative folder that happens to contain a different installation of an any given `libstdc++` release, GCC should ignore this suggestions only for `libstdc++`

I have no problem compiling GCC, but I don't get how to force GCC to behave like I want to, for example a GCC 4.7.2 build always picks up the libstdc++ on my default GCC 4.6.3 installation which is clearly what I don't want.

What are the right flags to do so when building GCC ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no build flags that will force such behavior. `-I` anss all the other flags are not suggestions, they are absolute requirements which are never ignored. If you are brave enough to specify a search path that contains headers or libraries of a different compiler release (impossible to do by accident so you should be fully aware of what you are doing), you fully deserve the consequences.

A normal installation with a prefix should do most of what is needed. Configure with `--prefix=/path/to/your/installation`, then the only thing to change would be the default specs file. Add a `-rpath=/path/to/the/folder/where/your/libstdc++/sits` and you should be all set. The syntax of the specs file is described in `man gcc`.

Comment: my main problem is with build systems or pre-packaged script for building that are assuming that a given gcc installation lives under a certain path, in other words I need this because when I specify the location of my CC or CXX I don't want to mix stuff from other places, not even by mistake or by any given command. also rpath it's more like adding an option to the global pool, it's not mandatory for GCC to follow what is specified by rpath and I often found that option quite useless.

Comment: You will not mix things up. There's no reason for this to happen. Do you have any evidence to the contrary? I don't know what you mean by "global pool". I also have never experienced gcc ignoring any options so I cannot comment on this.

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer because ... well ... it's in topic, but I haven't solved my problem yet.